# Inserting data into mySQL database using PHP in 000webhost

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm still learning PHP/mySQL and for the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. I have also searched in stackoverflow but still my table appears to be blank. I used phpmyadmin to create the table and my host is 000webhost. Thanks in advance!

This is my PHP script:

```
<?php
//Create a Database connection
$servername = "mysql4.000webhost.com";
$username = "a6212396_user";
$password = "secret123";
$dbname = "a6212396_querydb";
$tbl_name = "table1";

//Create connection
mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("cannot select DB");
$result = $name = $email = $message = $human = "";
$errName = $errEmail = $errMessage = $errHuman = "";
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $human = intval($_POST['human']);
    $from = 'webmaster@itsnano.5gbfree.com';
    //your email address where you wish to receive mail
    $to = 'wasim.kabir1992@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'MESSAGE FROM YOUR WEB SITE';
    $headers = "From:$from\r\nReply-to:$email";
    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n\n Message: $message";
// Check if name is entered
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
$errName = "Please enter your name.";
} else {
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
}
// Check if email is entered
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
$errEmail = "Please enter your email address.";
} else {
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
// check if e-mail address is valid format
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $errEmail = "Invalid email format.";
}
}
//Check if message is entered
if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
$errMessage = "Please enter your message.";
} else {
$message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
}

//Check if simple anti-bot test is entered
if (empty($_POST["human"])) {
$errHuman = "Please enter the sum.";
} else {
 if ($human !== 12) {
 $errHuman = 'Wrong answer. Please try again.';
    }
}
if (!$errName && !$errEmail &&  !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
    $result='<div class="alert alert-success"><h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Message sent!</h2><h3>Thank you for contacting us. Someone will be in touch with you soon.</h3></div>';
} else {
    $result='<div class="alert alert-danger"><h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span> Message sending FAILED!</h2></h3>Please fill up the form correctly.</h3></div>';
   }
}
//sanitize data inputs
function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
$data = (filter_var($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
return $data;

//Insert the data into database
 //From file
 $sql1 = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (Name, Email, Message) VALUES ('John Doe', 'example@example.domain.com', 'Is it working??')";
 mysql_query($sql1) or die ('Error SQL!' .$sql1. '<br/>'.mysql_error());


 //From Website
 $sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (Name, Email, Message) VALUES ($name, $email, $message)";
 mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error SQL!' .$sql. '<br/>'.mysql_error());


 //Closing the databse connection
 mysql_close();
}
//end form processing script
?>
```

This is my form field:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])?>">


<!--when submit button is clicked, show results here-->
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
<?php echo $result;?>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><span class="required">*    </span> Name:</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
<span class="required small"><?php echo $errName;?></span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><span class="required">*</span> Email: </label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="you@domain.com" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
<span class="required small"><?php echo $errEmail;?></span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="message" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><span class="required">*</span> Query:</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<textarea class="form-control" row="4" name="message" placeholder="Ask your query?"><?php echo $message;?></textarea>
<span class="required small"><?php echo $errMessage;?></span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="human" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><span class="required">*</span> Human Test:</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<h3 class="human">6 + 6 = ?</h3>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Your Answer" value="<?php echo $human;?>">
<span class="required small"><?php echo $errHuman?></span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
<button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
</div>
<!--end Form--></form>
```

First, I have tried with mysqli api, after that I switched into mysql api since my PHP version in 000wbhost is low (5.2.*) and MySQL version is 5.1.

Comment: You need to close this function `function test_input($data) {` before your insert query

Comment: Thanks for your help. But now it game me an sql error: <br/>Error SQL!INSERT INTO table1 (Name, Email, Message) VALUES (, , )
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , )' at line 1

Comment: You values must be in `quotes`!! Stop using deprecated `mysql` instead use `mysqli or PDO`

Comment: I am using quotes for my values, and as for the mysqli api I am trying that now. I let you know the result.

Comment: It is working!! But there is no data from the website. Can you please help me out here?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The problem is SOLVED!!

Comment: Please , stop using mysql , use PDO or mysqli , these are really better